# NSSortDescriptor Nil Objects Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nssortdescriptor

I am using Parse in my app and when fetching my objects, I need to use an `NSSortDescriptor`. I can sort via a specific field/property, but any objects where that sort field is nil, come first in the results.

Can I have it so that nil objects in the sort field come last?

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to make zero come last in an ascending sort. My approach would be one of: (a) a block-based `NSComparator` that you write that forces nulls last, or (b) use `NSSortDescriptor`, but temporarily or permanently replace the nulls with a max value that's out of bounds in your data, or (c) use `NSSortDescriptor`, sort simply, then move the nulls to the end manually.

If you're not married to a sort descriptor, I'd go with the comparator idea (a) as follows: (guessing that you're sorting PFObjects based on some property)...

```
NSComparator comparator = ^(PFObject *objA, PFObject *objB) {
    id someProperyA = objA[@"someProperty"];
    id someProperyB = objB[@"someProperty"];

    // two nulls are equal
    if (!somePropertyA && !somePropertyB) return NSOrderedSame;

    // any single null is bigger in your world, so sort it last
    if (!somePropertyA) return NSOrderedDescending;
    if (!somePropertyB) return NSOrderedAscending;

    // otherwise use compare, or whatever you were planning to use
    // with your NSSortDescriptor
    return [somePropertyA compare:somePropertyB];
};
```